# avoid computing whole cartesian product (python itertools)

Tags: python, python-itertools

My goal is to find any permutation of a diagonal in a nxn matrix (2 <= n <= 15). The matrix consists of zeros and ones.

Currently I do it like this:

```
  indices = [[j for j, x in enumerate(row) if x == 1] 
                for row in self.matrix]
  cart = list(itertools.product(*indices))
  cart = [list(tup) for tup in cart]
  cart = filter(lambda dia: len(list(set(dia))) == len(dia), cart)
  return cart
```

This works fine if the matrix is not too large, but otherwise it fails with:
MemoryError

So is there a way to avoid the whole computation of cart? so that it for example one permutation is found, the computation stops?

Comment: You are creating multiple copies for no reason. Remove the list call on `itertools.product(*indices)` and the `cart = [list(tup) for tup in cart]` is also unnecessary. Also the filter would be slower than just doing it using a list comp.

Comment: Why are you doing `list(itertools.product(*indices))`? You may easily filter data lazily. Can you add information on Python version used? Python 2.x and 3.x would be slightly different here.

Comment: I'm using python 2.7. how can I filter it lazily? 

Since I have a list of indices per row, I want to select one index per item, how else can this be done without itertools.product ?

Comment: `cart = [p for p in itertools.product(*indices) if len(set(p)) == len(p)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply make all the evaluations lazy by not calling `list` on the result of [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and using [`itertools.ifilter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilter) in place of `filter`:

```
from itertools import ifilter, product

indices = [[j for j, x in enumerate(row) if x == 1]  for row in self.matrix]
cart = product(*indices)
found_cart = next(ifilter(lambda dia: len(set(dia)) == len(dia), cart), None)
```

`next` returns the first case where the predicate in `ifilter` is `True` or returns `None` in case there is no matching item.

The *computation* stops once a matching item is found.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the last part of your code to have it just return the first answer:

```
def foo(matrix):
    indices = [[j for j, x in enumerate(row) if x == 1] for row in matrix]

    # this part is changed, very simple and efficient now
    for dia in itertools.product(*indices):
        if len(set(dia)) == len(dia):
            return dia
```

In other words, don't be so clever with `filter` and lambda and all that--it's unnecessary.

Comment: Hehe yes, I'm kind of trying to use list comprehension and lambda expressions all the time, but I also think its nicer to read than for loops.

Comment: @ph0t3k: Most people would find the for-if in my answer to be a lot easier to read than `next(ifilter(lambda...`.  Think of future maintainers of your code.